# Jackson Mapper integer from json parsed as double with drong precision

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

Greeting.
I had a working solution, but after making a multiple changes on project it doesn't work anymore.

The problem:
Front-end sending integer value `565656` which is an attribute of the object converted by Jackson `ObjectMapper`. i need to get a double with precision 2 from this integer value.

This is the java model:

```
public class Item {

    private int condoId;
    private Integer itemId;
    private String owner;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=1, max=60)
    private String itemTitle;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=1, max=1000)
    private String itemDescr;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=1, max=45)
    private String itemEmail;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=1, max=16)
    private Double itemPrice;
}
```

Was working before:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

    *In controller, received a request data as string data*

             ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
             JsonNode node = null;
             node = mapper.readTree(data);
             Item item = mapper.convertValue(node.get("item"), Item.class);
            NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat(".00");
            item.setItemPrice(Double.parseDouble(formatter.format(item.getItemPrice())));
```

Now this solution giving me wrongly formatted  values (like `5.67657654E8`) from `567657654`.
What is the way to convert the received integer attribute to the required double?

PS. in `PostgreSQL` DB it is stored as `numeric(10,2)`.

**EDIT:**
probably the right question is - why the received `int 567657654`  from json POST data is deserialized to `double` `5.67657654E8`, which is a "solid" 5 + decimal `.67657654E8`

Comment: There is ***no such thing*** as a 'double with precision 2'. The precision of `double` is *fixed* at 53 binary digits.

Comment: you can do something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520781/serialize-a-double-to-2-decimal-places-using-jackson in setter for customization while deserialize.

Comment: @EJP I guess he just wants to format with a couple of zeroes since int hasn't a decimal part anyways.

Comment: @m0skit0. right.But somehow it's formatted from the int `567657654` to double `5.67657654E8` which is a "solid" 5 and 0.67657654E8

Comment: So fix your question, and especially the title, but this is just scientific notation. There isn't even any change in precision. The only issue is why an `int` came back as a `double`, and the answer to that lies directly in your own code, where you have declared `Double itemPrice`. Don't use floating-point for money. This should be a `BigDecimal`.

Comment: Integer doesn't have any decimal part, why you want to convert to double.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no precision problem here. Every digit of the input appears in the output. You are merely seeing, but not recognizing, scientific notation for floating-point. The reason for that lies on your own code: you have an `itemPrice` column declared as `NUMERIC(10,2)` but you have mapped that to a Java `Double`. This is not correct: it is causing this problem; and it will cause untold others further down the track.

The correct Java type to use for that is not `Double`, or `double`, but `BigDecimal`.

*Never* use floating-point for money.